# Javascript Ajax reinitialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url-routing

I have a web application that I am moving towards an Ajax-based workflow. Currently, I load my Javascript with my own routing mechanism which is based on the page url. In order to keep track of the Ajax 'pages', I use hash tags. The problem that I ran into is how can I reinitialize pages when content changes? I can rerun my routing mechanism but I don't want to accidentally recreate and reattach existing events. I think in the ideal solution I would perform a global clean up for all events upon Ajax completion and reinitialize the whole Javascript. That way, I would never have to worry if an element is gone or if it has been attached to an event, or similar.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of jQuery's hashchange event:

```
$.on("hashchange", init);
```

With `init` being your routing function or initial function.

Here's an example of what I use:

```
function route() {
    var loc = (location.hash && location.hash.split("#")[0]) || location.pathname;

    if (loc.search("profile") !== -1) {
        // do profile page stuff
    }
    if (loc.search("home") !== -1) {
        // do home stuff
    }
}

$.on("hashchange", route);
```

Comment: If you're not passing any arguments, and only calling the one function, you can simplify it to `$.on('hashchange', route);` as the anonymous function wrapper is doing nothing for you.